# How to make a sound only play once

Tags: javascript

How do I make it play the sound only once I tap the spacebar and not when I'm holding it down and when I'm holding it down I want it to only play it once.

```
// makes my character jump
if (keys.jump && is_grounded) {
    yvel = jump;
    // plays a cat sound when I jump problem
    cat.play(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your event listener should be on `keydown` event to play the audio.

And then on another event listener `keyup` event, you can remove the audio element.

I can't help you more specifically without you posting your code.  Hope that helps!

Comment: txn i'll try it!

Comment: couldn't put the code in beacuse it said there is to much code so i'll try asking my friend but txn anywas.